# Executing HTTP requests one after another after successful response

Tags: node.js

I am executing the following code to run HTTP POST request in Node.js application and it is working fine.

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    //res.end('Hello World\n');

    var postData = {
              'name': 'in2_instance',
              'format': 'json',
              'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
            }

    var options = {
            url: 'http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_test_consumer',
            method: 'POST',
            body : JSON.stringify(postData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.kafka.v2+json'
            },

        }
        request(options, function(error, response, body){
            if(error) console.log(error);
            else {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

            // Upon Successful response, I need to execute another HTTP POST request here.
            }
        });

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

My question is, I need to execute 1 more HTTP POST request and 1 more HTTP GET request following with the each successful response. For example, from the above code, i need to execute another HTTP POST request upon successful response of the existing.

How can I call the other set of HTTP request one after another based on the successful response of the above?

Please advise or share me the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the same way as you are doing it for the first request.

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    //res.end('Hello World\n');

    var postData = {
              'name': 'in2_instance',
              'format': 'json',
              'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
            }

    var options = {
            url: 'http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_test_consumer',
            method: 'POST',
            body : JSON.stringify(postData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.kafka.v2+json'
            },

        }

        request(options, function(error, response, body){
            if(error) console.log(error);
            else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                var options1 = {
                    url: '<new URL>',
                    method: 'POST',
                    body : JSON.stringify(postData),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.kafka.v2+json'
                    },
                }

                request(options1, function(error, response2, body) {    
                    if(error) console.log(error);
                    else {
                            // Your GET request call
                    }
                }        
            }
        });
    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: It is working fine. If you know, please clarify this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554279/confluent-kafka-rest-proxy-asking-to-create-new-instance-every-time