# Confluent Kafka REST Proxy asking to create new INSTANCE every time

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am following the Confluent Kafka documentation for REST Proxy use.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html

In the "Produce and Consume JSON Messages" part, I have been using the following APIs

```
I.)
POST : "http://localhost:8082/topics/jsontest"
Header : "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json"
"Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"
JSON BODY : {"records":[{"value":{"foo":"bar"}}]}

II.)
POST : "http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer"
Header : "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json"
JSON BODY : {"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}

III.)
POST : "http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance/subscription"
Header : "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"
JSON BODY : {"topics":["jsontest"]}

IV.) 
GET : "http://localhost:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance/records"
Accept : "application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json"
```

I am able to execute the above APIs successfully.

My problem is, I need to create new INSTANCE (for ex: my_consumer_instance) every time when i want to test this functionality. So, I can't test this at real-time without changing anything on the code. I can't test this streaming of sending data.

Is this way it works? How to avoid creating new INSTANCE every time (or) Is there any other way that I need to be handling this part?

If someone knows about it, please share your ideas to fix this.

Comment: Why don't you clean-up (delete the instance) after you are done. In that case, you won't need a code change to test it every time.

Comment: It is a string for ex: "my_consumer_instance". how to clean and create new dynamically? Could you suggest?

Comment: Yes, you are right! They have an API for DELETE instance. I can DELETE existing instance.